# Why is text entered in my UITextField just being recorded as nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to take a simple integer entered in a UITextField and validate that against the "correct answer"—but I keep getting the error that the value is nil "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

What am I doing wrong?

At the top I define the variables

```
var answerMessage = String("No Answer")
var answerLabel: SKLabelNode!
var answerField: UITextField?
var answerModal: SKNode?
```

and then these are the functions

```
func validateAnswer() {
            // Convert the entered text to an integer
            if let userAnswer = Int(answerField?.text ?? "") {
                // Use the integer value
                print("The entered number is: \(userAnswer)")
            } else {
                // Invalid input, show an error message
                print("Invalid input, please enter a valid number")
            }
           
            // Display a message with the error percentage and the correct answer
            if userAnswer == correctAnswer {
                let answerMessage = "Wow you got a PERFECT answer!! The answer was \(correctAnswer)!"
                print (answerMessage)
                //let createlabel = SKAction.sequence ([createAnswerLabel])
            }
            else {
                // Calculate the error percentage
                let diff = abs(userAnswer - correctAnswer)
                errorPercentage = Int((Double(diff) / Double(correctAnswer)) * 100)
                
                // Determine if the error is positive or negative
                let direction = userAnswer > correctAnswer ? "high" : "low"
                
                // display correct answer
                let answerMessage = "Almost! Your answer is \(errorPercentage)% \(direction), the answer is \(correctAnswer)."
                print (answerMessage)
            }
        return
        }

 func createAnswerLabel () {
        let answerLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "\(answerMessage)")
        answerLabel.fontColor = .black
        answerLabel.position = CGPoint(x: answerLabel.position.x, y: answerLabel.position.y - 50)
        answerModal!.addChild(answerLabel)
        }
```

Comment: Do you use storyboards to create your label ? In that case, you need to make your textfield an outlet in your code and link it from the storyboard.

Comment: Which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: Hangar, the error is on the "answerModal!.addChild(answerLabel)" line in the last function.

I don't use storyboards, although thank you for the suggestion, Shawn!